# Laravel 7 Error: fresh install on live server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a fresh Laravel 7 app that I wanted to put on a live server. There, I am getting this message:

`PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Illuminate\Foundation\Application::handle(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, $type = self::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface::handle(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, int $type = self::MASTER_REQUEST, bool $catch = true) in /usr/www/users/myuser/mydomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 29`

I tried changing the PHP version running on the server: PHP 7.2, PHP 7.3, PHP 7.4
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Have you checked this section https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#symfony-5-related-upgrades

Comment: Yes but, it's a fresh install, not an upgrade

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `Laravel7`

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31803

There is already a `pull request` in place:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/31806